# JSF displays code instead of translation

Tags: jsf, internationalization, resourcebundle, faces-config

I'm new to JSF. Right now I am developing a JSF project. I have 2 properties files, configured correctly. (tested on previous Servlet/ JSP proj.)

The problem is when I try to get the value from the property file, I get just a code typed in my browser like this:

```
Welcome, "#{bundle.dude}"
```

But it should be like:

```
Welcome, dude
```

That's my problem.
My faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>ru</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>i18n.MediaPortal</base-name>
            <var>bundle</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

i18n property files are located at src/main/resources/i18n/ dir

Every answer is appreciated.
Thanks in advice.
Nazar

Comment: Have a proper mapping on the `FacesServlet` in web.xml.

Comment: Is the rest of JSF framework working correctly? Seems that expressions are not being properly evaluated, instead of bundle problem.